# Numerical integration of double integral with two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically integrate the following double integral in MATHEMATICA. This question has also been asked at [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2070465)

[image: expression]

where $Im$ is the imaginary part of the expression, $i$ is the imaginary number, $x$ and $y$ are variables while $a, b, c$ and $Q$ are constants greater than 0.

Here is my attempt to solve this.

```
a = 3
b = 0.0137
c = 0.0023
Q = 6
NIntegrate[
  Im[Exp[-I x c + b (I x y/(y^a - I x))]]/x, {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, Q},
  AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

Is this the correct way of applying numerical integration with more than one variable? I am getting an error when I run this expression which reads as

> evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the \region with boundaries {{[Infinity], 0.},{0, 6}}.

Can anyone please guide me to correct the implementation of the expression given above.

Comment: Your integrand should be `Im[Exp[-I x c + b (I x y/(y^a - I x))]]/x` not `Im[Exp[-I x c + b (i x y/(y^a - I x))]]/x`. Voting to close.

Comment: This integral does not converge because for small `x` the integrand behaves as `1/x`.

Comment: @Artes Is there any way around to avoid that? If the x values are restricted to be a larger value then it should work, right?

Comment: When you simultaneously cross-post the same question (https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2070465), you should mention that in both posts.

Comment: @Artes: The integral under consideration converges at the origin in view of `ComplexExpand[
   Normal[Series[
     Im[Exp[-I x c + b (I x y/(y^a - I x))]]/x , {x, 0, 1}]]] /. {x ->
     r*Cos[\[Phi]], y -> r*Sin[\[Phi]]}]` which results in `-(1/r)E^(-((137 r^3 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 Sin[\[Phi]])/(
   10000 (r^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + r^6 Sin[\[Phi]]^6))))
   Sec[\[Phi]] Sin[(23 r Cos[\[Phi]])/10000 - (
    137 r^5 Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Phi]]^4)/(
    10000 (r^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + r^6 Sin[\[Phi]]^6))]`..

Comment: @Artes:The command `NIntegrate[
 ComplexExpand[
  Normal[Series[
    Im[Exp[-I x c + b (I x y/(y^a - I x))]]/x , {x, 0, 1}]]], {x, 0, 
  0.1}, {y, 0, 0.1}, Exclusions -> {{x, y} == {0, 0}}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` results in `0.000092300457238432410335`, confirming the convergence at the origin. A simpler example of such sort is $\int_0^1\frac {\sin(\sqrt x)} x\,dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ComplexExpand the functions and integrate separately.(Because I am in a hurry, i don't show intermediate results)

```
ceRe = ComplexExpand[Re[(I x y)/(y^3 - I x)], 
          TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

ceIm = ComplexExpand[Im[(I x y)/(y^3 - I x)], 
          TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

intRe[x_] = Integrate[ceRe, {y, 0, 6}, Assumptions -> x > 0]

intIm[x_] = Integrate[ceIm, {y, 0, 6}, Assumptions -> x > 0]

ii[x_] = ComplexExpand[Im[Exp[-I x c + b*(intRe[x] + I intIm[x])]]/x, 
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] /. {b -> 137/10000, c -> 23/10000} //
   Simplify[#, x > 0] &

Plot[ii[x], {x, 0, 10000}]

nint = NIntegrate[ii[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 50]

(*   -0.989098   *)
```